# .net base.dispose() is closing other forms also.

Tags: .net, winforms, dispose

I am using two forms in my application lets Say A and B. While closing A I need to call base.dispose() in dispose method of A else after sometimes I see some unexpected behavior by the application because of memory problems. 
Form B is a locally declared form by Form B = new Form and displayed by ShowDialog method. 
When I am calling base.dispose() in form A, its closing the form B also. But I need to keep the form B open. Any suggestions ?

Thanks,
Abhinav

Answer (score 1):

Since Form A is owning Form B this is the expected behavior.

Move the declaration and creation of Form B to your app as a global resource in `Program.cs` and call its `Show()` method for FormB from Form A.

`ShowDialog` implies a modal dialog, which doesn't make sense in the scenario you described. If you really do want that, assign a global owner and use that in `ShowDialog(owner)`

BTW. Focus on that root cause memory problem instead of trying to implement a UI based watchdog functionality around it.

Comment: Both are created in Program.cs separately. They are not related to each other.

Comment: @abhinavp which version of the ShowDialog method are you using ShowDialog or ShowDialog(this) ?

Answer (score 0):

In your application settings you can define a shutdown mode (close on mainform or close on last form). Try setting it to close on last form.

Update: I just tried it myself and closing the caller (the form that calls ShowDialog() on another form also closes the dialog itself, which is by design I suppose.

However, using this code, I can create a dialog, close the caller and the dialog still exists:

```
// inside formA
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var owner = new Form();
    var dialog = new FormB();

    // attach to the dialog.button1.Click event to force a close
    // of the current formA instance.
    // button1.modifiers has (at least) to be set internal
    dialog.button1.Click += (x, y) => this.Close();
    dialog.ShowDialog(owner);

    dialog.Dispose();
    owner.Dispose();
}
```

Now If I click on button1 in FormB, FormA closes and Form B still exists.
FormA is not the MainForm.

Comment: I have a base desktop application, that is like not closed for a day. We have a predefined mechanism to implant Plugin/Addins in that application. Suppose I have created two addins, One addin inherits windows form and can show a popup. Sencond addin declares Form B = new Form() and does B.showDialog(). So where shall I define shutdown mode. I can not make change in the base application.

Comment: I thought your main form (the one that starts first) is Form A. Now by default, if you open Form B (without ShowDialog()) and close Form A, Form B closes, too, unless you change that. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0hzfysdc.aspx  HowEver, if that is not the case, I would suggest you override the Dispose Method in Form B and set a BreakPoint or throw an Exception. Maybe you can track down the caller from the StackTrace.

Comment: Now the problem is, Form B is declared as global variable in second addin (Form B = new Form() ) as we have to perform some action on this form based on some event occurred in the controls added to form B. How do I override Dispose method for it? as it's a global variable and used in multiple functions, I am not able to use 'using' also. Could you how can I override Dispose in this case ?

Comment: I added a possible solution to my current answer.